# How to set thread number for the parallel collections?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I can run scala's foreach in parallel like that:

```
val N = 100
(0 until N).par.foreach(i => {
   // do something
})
```

But how can I set thread number? I want something like that:

```
val N = 100
val NThreads = 5
(0 until N).par.foreach(NThreads, i => {
   // do something
})
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Every parallel collection keeps a `tasksupport` object which keeps a reference to thread pool implementation.

So, you can set the parallelism level through that object by changing the reference of `tasksupport` object to a new thread pool according to your need. eg:

```
def f(numOfThread: Int, n: Int) = {
 import scala.collection.parallel._
 val coll = (0 to n).par
 coll.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(numOfThreads))
  coll.foreach(i => {
   // do something
  })
}

f(2, 100)
```

For more info on configuring parallel collections you can refer http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html

Comment: This solution is creating and deleting threads on each call.  This can become a bottleneck when calling such methods in a tight loop.

Comment: @MichelLemay: Don't you think that was the requirement to set num of threads on demand? It obviously has a drawback but its more of an implementation detail and this example just explains how one can set num of threads for a parallel collection.

Comment: I thought it could reuse the default thread pool instead of creating and deleting threads..  It could have simply put a cap on the number of executing tasks. (I'm just discovering this as we speak)

Comment: While searching for a solution to my problem, I stumbled upon this: http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html  Which is a critique of java ForkJoin design.  Very instructive.

Comment: I had exactly the same implementation, it causes resource leak.

Comment: @AvseiytsevDmitriy Thanks, for the catch. upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 20):

Official Scala documentation provides a way to change the task support of a parallel collection like this:

```
import scala.collection.parallel._
val pc = mutable.ParArray(1, 2, 3)
pc.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(2))
```

Also it is mentioned that

> The execution context task support is set to each parallel collection by default, so parallel collections reuse the same fork-join pool as the future API.

It means that you should create single pool and reuse it. **This approach causes resource leak**:

```
def calculate(collection: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  val parallel = collection.par
  parallel.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(5))
  parallel.map(_ * 2).seq
}
```

Right way to do this would be to reuse existing pool:

```
val taskSupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(5))

def calculate(collection: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  val parallel = collection.par
  parallel.tasksupport = taskSupport
  parallel.map(_ * 2).seq
}
```