# Two threads accessing the same file in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing

I have a shell script that copies files into a location and another one that picks these up for further processing. I want to use multithreading to pick up files parallelly in Scala using a threadpool.

However, if there are two threads and two files, both of them are picking up the same file. I have tried the program a lot of times, and it always ends up like this. **I need the threads to pick up different files in parallel**.

Can someone help me out? What approaches can I use? If you could point me in the right direction that would be enough.

Comment: Don't launch a new task/thread until a new file appears. When a thread is finished with a file, it terminates.

Comment: @jwvh I'm not, if there are 2 files, the threadpool should assign two different threads for them, but two threads are getting assigned to 1 file. thats the problem

Comment: Launch each thread with the file it is supposed to work on. Each thread will only know about one file, the one it was given when launched. Don't launch a thread with the instructions, "Go out and find a file."

Comment: @jwvh that would work fine, but I will be working with a huge amount of files and I need them to pick up the files dynamically

Comment: You might create a file-lock for each file as it is processed, but you're asking for race conditions and other headaches. If the obvious and common-sense solution isn't right for you, why didn't you mention that in the question? I find it very hard to believe that your situation requires the design you've chosen.

Comment: @jwvh so, what would your approach be if you needed to process a huge amount of files parallely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a parallel sequence to do the processing in parallel.
You don't have to handle this logic yourself. for ex. the code could be like this:

```
newFiles:Seq[String] = listCurrentFilesNames()
newFiles.par.foreach { fileName =>
   processFile(fileName)
}
```

This code will be executed in parallel. and you could set the number of threads to a specific number as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725987/2201566

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using actors - for eg- for your reference - https://github.com/tsheppard01/akka-parallel-read-csv-file